# Custom async MediaTypeFormatter returning Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, owin, mediatypeformatter

I'm experiencing strange behavior with a custom MediaTypeFormatter, but only with an Owin Self-hosted WebApi.

With a standard .NET WebApi project hosted in IIS, the same formatter works fine.

Stepping through the program, `CanWriteType` in the Formatter is getting called multiple times. The exception logger is firing with an exception of `Cannot access a closed stream.`

Any insight would be very helpful! Removing the async nature of this formatter results in it working fine so It's mostly likely some weird threading issue. I'd like to stay with an asynchronous formatter and not use the `BufferedMediaTypeFormatter` if at all possible.

Stack Trace:

```
at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
   at System.IO.MemoryStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin loc)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<LoadIntoBufferAsync>b__0(Task copyTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<BufferResponseContentAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
```

Startup.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    public class TraceExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
           Trace.TraceError(context.ExceptionContext.Exception.ToString());
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            // Add in a simple exception tracer so we can see what is causing the 500 Internal Server Error
            config.Services.Add(typeof(IExceptionLogger), new TraceExceptionLogger());

            // Add in the custom formatter
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonFhirAsyncFormatter());

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonFhirAsyncFormatter());

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

Formatter:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class JsonFhirAsyncFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public JsonFhirAsyncFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json+fhir"));
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
        {
            using (StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
            {
                await streamwriter.WriteAsync("{\"test\":\"test\"}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("test")]
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("")]
        public async Task<string> Test()
        {
            // Eventually this will using an await method
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9000");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish...based on your code it seems that you are trying to reinvent the wheel...you can accomplish something like that using OWIN self hosted web api, give it a try

Comment: I am using OWIN to self host the web api. That's why I said "but only with an Owin Self-hosted WebApi." This is using OWIN. The question is related to a threading issue with the custom MediaTypeFormatter in the Startup.cs class which is the Owin startup class. I specifically followed the OWIN instructions here https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api to create an example project to show what the issue is.

Comment: Mmm, my bad....I just read until the middle of your question....ok, that article dates from 2013, and it's possibly an outdated code...I tryed this one and works like a charm..also the code is available on github: http://codeopinion.com/self-host-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: The only significant difference between the code from your link and the code above is a using statement in the Program Main method. Even when changing that, the same exception is found. With your test, did you setup a custom MediaTypeFormatter and pass the Accept Header with application/json+fhir as the content type. Your test may be passing because it's failing over to the standard newtonsoft JSON Formatter and not using the custom MediaTypeFormatter where the exception is being thrown. Other than the threading issue, this problem doesn't have much to do with the OWIN setup, that works fine.

Comment: I do appreciate your suggestions though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try this:

```
public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        using (StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
        {
            return streamwriter.WriteAsync("{\"test\":\"test\"}");
        }
    }
```

This is then not activating the Async stuff, and allows the Async to occur when needed.

However in my server (sqlonfhir) this function is implemented as

```
 public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writeStream);
        JsonWriter jsonwriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer);
        if (type == typeof(OperationOutcome))
        {
            Resource resource = (Resource)value;
            FhirSerializer.SerializeResource(resource, jsonwriter);
        }
        else if (typeof(Resource).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                Resource r = value as Resource;
                SummaryType st = SummaryType.False;
                if (r.UserData.ContainsKey("summary-type"))
                    st = (SummaryType)r.UserData["summary-type"];
                FhirSerializer.SerializeResource(r, jsonwriter, st);
            }
        }
        writer.Flush();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null); // Task.CompletedTask // When we update to .net 4.6;
    }
```

(And yes, I do my unit testing using OWIN self testing with this code too)

Comment: That did it. Looks like 
  writer.Flush();
  return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
was the magic!

Glad to see other FHIR users on here! Thanks Brian